# Transition Aborted for Failed FindRecord

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

So in my route I have the following code and it works just fine when running the app. But when I run my tests, the test fails with transition aborted instead of doing what it does when I run the app.

```
Model(params) {
  Return this.store.findRecord(service, 999);  
}
```

What am I missing here? I would of thought it would hit afterModel and just do what I expect.

Comment: is the API initiated from `findRecord` served properly?

Comment: Just making sure that the function is `model` and includes `return` vs `Model` and `Return`. Also, `service` doesn’t seem defined.

Comment: @GokulKathirvel What is the ask here?

Comment: @BuckDoyle Sorry, iPad keyboard kept capitalizing the text, lol. They are lower case

Comment: What is answering the API call in the test environment? What’s the response and how does it compare to what you get outside the test environment?